# Adding Routing to eliminate .SVC in REST service isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am building a dummy WCF REST service just for purposes of learning how it works (preparing for real service build).  I have the REST service working and responding with both JSON and POX formatting.  However, I cannot get the routing solution to work in order to eliminate the ".svc" file.  I am using VS 2010, WCF 4.0 and IIS 7.5 on Win Server 2008 R2.

Right now the URL works as:  "/api/rest/rest.svc/json/myMethod"  but I want to just have "/api/rest/json/myMethod".  I have found numerous articles here on SO and elsewhere which claims to remove the ".svc" file.  I believe I have it setup as instructed, but the project will not build because of an error in the Global.asax file.

It says to add the following to the Application_Start function:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), 
    typeof(RestService)));
```

I also added the following to the web.config:

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
     <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
          type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, 
      System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, 
      Culture=neutral, 
      PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

 </modules>
 <handlers>
     <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
        preCondition="integratedMode"
        verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
        type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, 
     System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
     PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
 </handlers>
```

I also added the aspNetCompatibility lines to the web.config and above the class in the svc.cs file.

Th issue is that I can't even get the project to build.  When I add the RouteTable.Routes.Add line to the global.asax and build it, I get the following errors:

> The type
>   'System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.Activation,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>
> The type or namespace name
>   'ServiceRoute' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Any ideas why this is failing?

Comment: make sure that "System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is referenced in the project, if it is make sure to add this to the web.config file as well.

Comment: Hey, if that first comment was the real answer, can you post it as such and then accept it as the answer? This question looks like its still unanswered when looking at the list of questions tagged as "WCF".

Answer (score 5):

make sure that "System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is referenced in the project, if it is make sure to add this to the web.config file as well. – Joakim Mar 25 at 19:03